# WCF consume Https Web Service, error: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, certificate

Gives me this error when connecting to an https web service server:

**Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority**

I am using message layer security, body is encrypted with the CERT certificate. The certificate validation for server certificate is not controlled by the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback delegate, this I can not use to accept the certificate. 
The https://xxxxx.com/callservice certificates are loaded on the calling server, what am I doing wrong? ¿some example to load certificate?

If you have any doubt tell me to answer you.

web.config

```html
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="SecurityBindingElement" type="Service.AsymetricSecurityExtentionElement, Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>    
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="SUMA">
          <MySecurityBindingElement/>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxxx.com/callservice"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SUMA" contract="ConsultaService"
        name="SUMA" behaviorConfiguration="cliBeh" >
        <identity>
          <certificateReference  storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="CERT"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="10" />

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="cliBeh">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="CERT"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
            
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the server not to return this error message, adding the following in the section of serviceCertificate

```js
<sslCertificateAuthentication trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser" certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
```

Tenemos estas opciones para que el servidor verifique la autenticidad del certificado emitido por el cliente. Se determina por el valor de **certificateValidationMode**, puede tomar estos valores.

**ChainTrust**: Busca un CA que sea válido y que esté registrado en el repositorio de autoridades de certificación del equipo, siguiendo una cadena de confianza. Este es el valor por defecto si no se especifica otro modo.

**PeerTrust**: Busca el certificado en el repositorio de Trusted People (personas de confianza) del equipo.

**PeerOrChainTrust**: Busca en base a una de las dos opciones anteriores.

**Custom**: Permite realizar una validación a medida. Para ello es necesario implementar una clase y asignarlo a la propiedad CustomCertificateValidatorType.

**None**: No se realiza validación alguna

a greeting